# How can I convert this .h5 model to a format my Windows machine can read? (OSError)

Tags: python-3.x, linux, windows, keras, hdf5

The model was originally created in Keras using a remote Linux environment that I no longer have access to. I now need to load the model on my Windows machine (a couple of years later). The program is written in Python if that's relevant.

The error I get:

*Exception has occurred: OSError
Unable to open file (bad superblock version number)
File "Directory/file”  line 13, in  model = load_model('model1.h5')*

I've tried installing h5py-2.10.0 so that I could install h5repack to convert the file to a readable format but when I do that, it says that h5repack is unable to open the file.

*h5repack error: < 'model1.h5' >: unable to open file*

I’m reluctant to try switching my machine over to Linux unless there’s no other solution.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The _`unable to open file`_ error message is not a good sign. (No news there.) You can also try to read with the **h5dump** utility from **The HDF Group**. If that also issues an error, it's likely the file is corrupt. That can occur when moving binary files between different operating systems (Linux to Windows). I ran into this with the SVHN dataset. How did you transfer to your Windows system?

Comment: I copied-and-pasted it from the remote server into my machine's folder. Nothing special! The other files seem to be fine but the .h5 one has this problem. 

Thanks for the tip about h5dump; I'll try that and see how it responds.

Comment: Can you install the h5dump or h5repack utility on the Linux machine and test the file before you copy it? That would be a good check to verify integrity. Alternatively, you could open an interactive Python on Linux, import h5py module, then try to open the file.